# Issues with switching stylesheets bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I've added a button to my website that changes the stylesheet to a different one. Here is how I am doing it:

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("button.city").click(function() { 

           $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "stylesheets/city.css"}); })


          });
```

HTML

```
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/city.css" title="city">
```

.

```
<button type="button" class="theme city btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
    </button>
```

Now the issue that arises from this is when you click on the button bootstrap files appears to unload. How would I keep it so bootstrap does not unload or what ever it is doing to not effect my HTML?

(Click on the little tree Icon at bottom of the index page)

***[WEBSITE](http://shanebacon.com)***

EDIT: It appears that the better contact form styling is being effected too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 2

First posted code works fine. Below is how it is ***supposed*** to be done according to the standards.

You should have two css link tags (stylesheet & alternate stylesheet) with title reflecting the name of your theme

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css" title="main">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/city.css" title="city">
```

To switch a theme you should use `disabled = true | false`

I wrote a small jQuery code to change themes

```
function changeTheme (name){ 
  $('link[rel*=style][title]').each(function(i, sheet){ 
    sheet.disabled = true; 
    if($(sheet).attr('title') == name) sheet.disabled = false;
  }); 
}

$("button.city").click(function() { 
   changeTheme('city');
});
```

---

#### First answer

The selector you are using is replacing all the stylesheets with `city.css`.

You have to change only the `main.css` to `city.css`

You can probably give a name attribute to your `<link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" name="mainCSS">`

And then use a script like below to replace that specific css file

```
$("button.city").click(function() { 
   $("link[rel=stylesheet][name='mainCSS']").attr({href : "stylesheets/city.css"});
});
```

Hope this helps.